# iPhone:How can I shuffle buttons in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have many no. of buttons on my view and I want to shuffle the buttons(change in position) then how can I shuffle the button in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `arc4random()`

and change position of your buttons

In your `.h file` : `UIButton *buttonsarray[10];`

In your `.m file` :

```
  // Make array of button using following way.I used this method to creates button and you can use yours.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];

      float y = 5;
      int x = 0;
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
     {
        count ++;
        buttonsarray[i] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        buttonsarray[i].frame =  CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100);
       [buttonsarray[i] setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         x = x + 105;
        [self.view addSubview:b[i]];
        if(count == 3)
       {
        count = 0;
        x = 0;
        y = y+ 105;
      }


    }
}


  // This function will soufflé your buttons
 - (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
   {
     int n = 10;
     int swaper;
     for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
     {
       int r = arc4random()%n;
       if(r != swaper){
        swaper = r;
        CGRect r1 = buttonsarray[i].frame;      
        buttonsarray[i].frame = buttonsarray[swaper].frame;
        buttonsarray[swaper].frame = r1; 

        n--;
    }

  }
}
```

Hope,this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

1. Make an Array with a group of CGPoints you will need to store the points as strings.
2. In the layoutSubViews method set something like this:

   ```
    -(void)layoutSubViews{
      [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
         CGPoint newPoint = CGPointFromString([positionsArray objectAtIndex:idx]);
        object.frame = CGRectMake(newPoint.x,newPoint.y,object.frame.size.width,object.frame.size.height);
   }];
   ```

   }
3. Then you will need to shuffle the positions in the positions array, you can see an example method here :[How to Shuffle an Array](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/shuffling-arrays.html)
4. Now every time you need to Shuffle the positions you can call `-(void)setNeedsLayout` on your view.

There are more options but that was the first I thought of.

Good Luck